# i got an error 404, The requested resource is not available

Tags: spring-mvc

- i got an error HTTP Status 404 - /FirstSpringMVCProject/welcome.html

i got an in console is

1. please help me out.

I'm quite new to spring and spring mvc application.

```html
`Apr 24, 2019 1:02:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: Completed initialization in 2771 ms
Apr 24, 2019 1:02:06 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /FirstSpringMVCProject/
```

- This is my web.xml file

web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>
  
  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern></url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

- This is my dispatcher file

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">  
   
   <bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
   
   <bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.amol.hellocontroller.HelloController"/>
   
   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
     <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
     <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

- this is controller class

HelloController.java

```html
package com.amol.hellocontroller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class HelloController extends AbstractController {

 @Override
 protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
  ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
  modelAndView.addObject("welcomeMessage", "Hi User, wlocme to the first Spring mvc appliction");
  
  return modelAndView;
 }

}
```

- HelloPage.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

 <h1>first spring mvc application</h1>
 <h2>${welcomeMessage}</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the url pattern in your configuration. Try following and check if that works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FirstSpringMVCProject</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FirstSpringMVCProject/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Based on your error logs,

> WARNING: No mapping for GET /FirstSpringMVCProject/

Your application context root is `/FirstSpringMVCProject` hence you need to define your url pattern which matches the context root.